# Stuck in Application-defined or object-defined error excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

Have a worksheet with multiple pivot tables and each pivot table has multiple filters. The particular filter "Month" (field - "Month") is collection of month end dates i.e. 11/30/23, ......12/31/23.The data grows each month and the next month, month field  will include "1/31/2024".
Periodically, in the worksheet some pivot tables are refreshed for a specific date i.e. "10/31/2023" and some with a range on dates from beginning date to end date i.e. "10/31/2023" ..... "12/31/2023" (all 3 dates). The code that I have works with no issue for a specific date that is identified on a cell i.e. Range("B2") i.e. specific date "12/31/2023"

```
With ActiveSheet
    .PivotTables("PivotTable1").RefreshTable
    .PivotTables("PivotTable1").Pivot Fields("Month").ClearAllFilters
    .PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Month").CurrentPage = Range("B2").Value`
```

However, when I want to update a pivot table filter based on multiple month end dates, i.e. "10/31/2023", "11/30/2023" and "12/31/2023" that are identified on cells, i.e. Range("B4") beginning date "10/31/2023" and Range("B2") ending date "12/31/2023", I use the following code which I get  "Application-defined or object-defined error"

```
    .PivotTables("PivotTable2").RefreshTable
    .PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Month").ClearAllFilters
    .PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Month").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlDateBetween, _      
            Value1:=Range("B4").Value, Value2:=Range("B2").Value`
```

To correct the problem I tried to use Currentpage method, however I couldn't get it to work. I am really stuck and getting that complacent error "Application-defined or object-defined error". Can anybody please provide a solution?

Thanks in advance

Tried the codes as I mentioned in the "Ask a question" section, I do have an issue with the second piece of code, I am expecting somebody to resolve the syntax or another issue that I do not know, to make the code work

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised the following works as the Range has an implied parent object.

```
.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Month").CurrentPage = Range("B2").Value
```

Since you are in a with block within your code, you can assume the activesheet...

Note the dots or periods before the range below.

```
.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Month").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlDateBetween, _      
            Value1:=.Range("B4").Value, Value2:=.Range("B2").Value
```

Comment: I am using the code assuming the ActiveSheet  as you mentioned 
    .PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Month").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlDateBetween, _      
            Value1:=.Range("B4").Value, Value2:=.Range("B2").Value, however as soon as I do that I get "Application-defined or object-defined error" If I change the code not to add filters but use CurrentPage, then I can only use a specific date but not range of dates.

Comment: Please cancel my previous comment and replace with this short comment, noted the periods before the range as suggested, I still get "Application-defined or object-defined error" when I ran the code